# PHP OOP Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

I'm doing a project with PHP OOP. But I'm getting error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ..../PhotoSection.php on line 12.
The below is my source code.

class DatabaseAdapter for connect to database

```
<?php

class DatabaseAdapter {

    protected $_pdo;

    function connect() {
        if (!$this->_pdo) {
            try {
                $this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", "xxx", "123456");
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->_pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                $this->_pdo->exec("set character_set_client='utf8'");
                $this->_pdo->exec("SET character_set_results='utf8'");
                $this->_pdo->exec("SET collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    function disconnect() {
        $this->_pdo = null;
    }

}
```

class DatabaseBusiness

```
require 'DatabaseAdapter.php';

class DatabaseBusiness extends DatabaseAdapter {

    protected $_table = "";
    protected $_primaryKey = "";

    function __construct() {
        parent::connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        parent::disconnect();
    }

}
```

class PhotoSection

```
<?php

class PhotoSection extends DatabaseBusiness {

    function __construct() {
        $this->_table = "photo_section";
        $this->_primaryKey = "id";
    }

    function selectAll() {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare("select * from ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($this->_table));
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            exit();
        }

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

now I include to template to display data

```
<?php
include_once 'libraries/DatabaseBusiness.php';
include_once 'libraries/PhotoSection.php';
$photoSection = new PhotoSection();
$photos = $photoSection->selectAll();
?>
```

I've read the questions duplicate but I have declared and initialized _pdo in DatabaseAdapter and extends it, so I dont know why error.
thanks for any helping

Comment: sidenote: you can't bind table names

Comment: @Ghost thanks. It's a my mistake. I will edit.

Comment: By adding "parent::__construct()" to class PhotoSection is ok

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand about the protected key word in php:

we use protected scope when we want to make your variable/function visible only in all classes that extend current class including its parent class

make this `protected $_pdo;` to `global $_pdo;`
in your DatabaseAdapter file.

Comment: Yes. I use protected $_pdo in DatabaseAdapter. DatabaseBusiness extends DatabaseAdapter and PhotoSection extends DatabaseBusiness. So I think PhotoSection can use $_pdo, where's my wrong?

Comment: i said please change that to global and see if that solves the probelm

Comment: I know your solution can solve my problem, but my mistake is don't call connect() function, so $_pdo is not initialized. anyway, thanks for helping.